# JVM: где находится TLAB?

Tags: java, память, jvm

Мною была прочитана статья на [хабре о TLAB](https://habr.com/post/332708/)
Понятно, что у каждого трэда есть свои выделенные куски памяти.
Но откуда они выделяются? Из хипа? Наблюдаю в Visual VM: Heap 470mb + metaspace(permgen) 83mb = 553 mb, но linux centos (htop) говорит, что памяти выделено 995 mb. Значит ли это что как раз недостающие (995-553) 442 mb выделены под tlab-ы?

Answer (score 3):

Как-то невнимательно вы читали. TLAB - это просто участок младшего поколения кучи, выделенный конкретному потоку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помимо кучи и метаспейcа у JVM есть ещё стековая и off-heap память.